# Apple Transporter error code ITMS-4140 & ITMS-6002

Tags: ios, game-center-leaderboard

I'm using Apple's Transporter to update my GameCenter Achievements & Leaderboards. All of my leaderboards that are already on GC are grouped under Leaderboard Sets. When I try to verify/upload the itmsp package with the updated metadata.xml (updated as in adding one new leaderboard), transporter returns me the following errors

ERROR ITMS-4140: "This leaderboard must belong to at least one leaderboard set" at Software/SoftwareMetadata/SoftwareGameCenter (MZItmspSoftwareGameCenterPackage)

ERROR ITMS-6002: "Updates to Leaderboards are not available because the app has Leaderboard Sets" at Software/SoftwareMetadata/SoftwareGameCenter (MZItmspSoftwareGameCenterPackage)

However, I don't see an xmlelement where I could define what leaderboard set the added leaderboard should belong to.

Is Apple only allowing uploads if I don't have leaderboard sets?!

here's the xml part of the leaderboard I am trying to add

```
<leaderboard position="233">
    <leaderboard_id>TEST UPLOAD</leaderboard_id>
    <reference_name>TEST UPLOAD LEADERBOARD</reference_name>
    <sort_ascending>true</sort_ascending>
    <locales>
      <locale name="en-US">
      <title>TEST UPLOAD LEADERBOARD</title>
      <formatter_suffix> Score</formatter_suffix>
      <formatter_type>FIXED_POINT_2_PLACE_WITH_COMMA_SEPARATOR</formatter_type>
      </locale>
   </locales>
</leaderboard>
```

appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, the answer is yes, you cannot update leaderboards because you are using sets. However, I was able to delete all my leaderboard sets in iTunes Connect and then my .itmsp package uploaded successfully. My game is not yet live and this route was faster than creating 90 leaderboards manually.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.